# "Flattening" a cell array

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell-array, multidimensional-array

I have created a function which takes vectors for input variables and returns a cell array for each set of inputs. The final output variable (out) seems to consist of a 2x1 cell containing two 1x5 cells. I have provided a screenshot of this below:

[image: Screenshot of current output]

I am just trying to figure out how to flatten the cell array (out) to be a 2x5 cell array.

Comment: `vertcat(cell_array1{:})` is one way.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly, I did not think of using vertcat to combine them. Although I suppose you can use : due to linear indexing.

Comment: @Divakar, how about adding that as an answer? In my opinion, it's better that way, even if the answer is very simple/short. As it stands, it appears to be unanswered on the front page.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One way to achieve that would be -

```
vertcat(cell_array1{:})
```

Comment: Since this is the first google answer, I think mentioning **horzcat** could help in the horizontal way.

Answer (score 5):

If your cell has unequal number of elements in each row , maybe this might work better

```
vector=[cell_array{:}]
```